# Can I emit a block shorter than internal state of (any) Xorshift PRNG without having to compute the full block?

Tags: random-number-generator

[Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) family pseudo-random number generators have a variety of different internal state sizes.

Let's take one of this family called [xorshift1024*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift#xorshift*).

My question is:

Having xorshift1024* a internal state of 1024-bits, can I generate a block shorter than 1024-bits without having to compute the entire 1024-bits output before the internal state cycles to the next?

Comment: Ummmm, have you looked at the implementation on the wiki page you linked to?  That would give you the answer...

Comment: @poncho Yes, but I don't know how to read C code yet. If you know how to answer, I ask to do it, just an "yes" or "not" for me is enough.

Comment: Note: There is a growing caucus that suggests no one should use C/C++ for new applications.  [Rust](https://www.theregister.com/2022/12/09/linux_kernel_61_column/) is now used in phones and the Linux kernel as a safer alternative.

Comment: @PaulUszak I like Rust, but honesty, C/C++ is rather portable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you virtually always generate a shorter output block than the state. In the case of `xorshift1024*` you output `t * 1181783497276652981` where `t` is a mangled and iterated variable acting over the internal state array `x`. That's a 64 bit value, and the return value from that function.

You'll only output state sized blocks for the simplest of this class of generators like `xorshift32/64` which feature 32 and 64 bit state sizes respectively.